# Multiple functions compact form

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

I have a sort of silly question...

I need to define two functions in the following way

```
uV1[q_] := uV1[q] = 
   (2 \[Pi] (1 + r1 q - 
      r1 q E^(-2  q d)))/(\[Epsilon] q ((1 + r1 q ) (1 + r2 q) - 
      r1 r1 q^2 E^(- 2 q d)));

uV2[q_] := uV2[q] = 
   (2 \[Pi] (1 + r2 q - 
      r2 q E^(-2  q d)))/(\[Epsilon] q ((1 + r1 q ) (1 + r2 q) - 
      r1 r1 q^2 E^(- 2 q d)));
```

As you can see these two are equal, the only difference is the 1 and the 2 placed in both expression. My question is: is there a compact way to write it up???
Thanks

Comment: You could give r1 or r2 as an additional argument: e..e. uv[q_,r_]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two functions do *not* share the same *formula*. However they share the same *denominator*:

```
numerator[r_, q_, d_] := numerator[r, q, d] = (2 \[Pi] (1 + r q - r q E^(-2  q d)))

(* there was a product r1 r1 that I wrote as r1^2, hope it's ok *)   
denominator[r1_, r2_, q_, d_] := \[Epsilon] q ((1 + r1 q ) (1 + r2 q) - r1^2 q^2 E^(- 2 q d)))
```

The `uV1` function uses `r1` in the *numerator* while `uV2` appears to be using `r2`:

```
(* uV1 *)
uV1[r1_, r2_, q_, d_] := uV1[r1, r2, q, d] = numerator[r1, q, d] / denominator[r1, r2, q, d]

(* uV2 *)
uV2[r1_, r2_, q_, d_] := uV2[r1, r2, q, d] = numerator[r2, q, d] / denominator[r1, r2, q, d]
```

Therefore, unless you're interested in [*Piecewise*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html), it's probably better to use *two* distinct definitions.

Comment: Is there a reason to put r1, r2 and d as variables in the brackets???

Comment: @SoterX I guess it depends on how you want to structure the scope of your variables and functions; I avoid defining functions that use variables that are not passed in their argument list, especially when I don't know how these 'global; variables are set; you can leave them out of the argument list as long as you're sure you know what you're doing